# How to compute an exponentially weighted covariance matrix function in R?

Tags: r, covariance, covariance-matrix

Is there a function the calculates an exponentially weighted covariance matrix in R?

I recall seeing a function some time ago... I cannot turn up any thing in "R Search" or Task View pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slow morning, or too little coffee?

1. Go to http://rseek.org
2. Type in 'weighted covariance'
3. Hit the 'Functions' tab.
4. Pick one of the four or five suggestions functions / packages.

Comment: A bit of both! Thanks Dirk. I had been using : http://www.r-project.org/search.html but this is a much better resource. Thanks